# Physical significance of Taylor and Maclaurin series - What is the significance of defining a Maclaurin series in Mathematical Physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, equilibrium

In physics, usually [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) is used to express a quantity which keep changes with coordinate. For example the potential energy of a molecule changes with coordinate, so we express the potential energy as a Taylor expansion with respect to the coordinate about the equilibrium configuration.

I am confusing this with the [Maclaurin series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) in mathematics. If the equilibrium position is zero, it is Maclaurin series. We have the freedom to fix the equilibrium position at zero. In short, what is the physical significance of Maclaurin series? or else, what is the need of defining a Maclaurin series? Any physical interests on Maclaurin series?

One more question I would like to add. If a quantity is changing with respect to its coordinate and doesn't have an equilibrium at any of its configuration, then how we can express it? Taylor series can be applied only if the quantity is changing about an equilibrium configuration?

Comment: I'm not an authority on this, but as far as I know a Maclaurin series is a special case of a Taylor series, so I can't imagine any special significance (someone may correct me).  But to answer your last question: a Taylor series can be applied at any well-behaved point in a well-behaved region, equilibrium or not.  In the equilibrium case, $f'(x-a)=0$ at $x=a$ (slope is zero at equilibrium), that's all I think.

Comment: BTW, Taylor/McLaurin series are used in no small part because we can choose to truncate the series at an arbitrary length with confidence that we know the resulting uncertainty in our calculation.

Comment: Yeah, as garyp mentioned, a Maclaurin series is just a special case of a Taylor series at the origin. Therefore, asking the question "what is the physical significance of a Maclaurin series?" is logically equivalent to asking the question "what is the physical significance of a Taylor series?". A Taylor series is generally used to approximate something complicated in order to make it more symbolically manageable.

Comment: @garyp:If I have a well behaved function randomly varying around a small region, then can I express the function as a Taylor expansion? A well defined function is some function having unique values for each input, right? I think a random function can also be well behaved.

Comment: What do you mean by "random function"?   In order for a function to have a Taylor series expansion at a point, it must exist at the point, be differentiable to all orders at the point in question, and a region around that point.   Most elementary functions (made up of polynomials, trig functions, exponentials, rational functions of the above) would qualify.  I'm not sure what the exact formal conditions are.  There are many smooth-looking functions that don't qualify.  It doesn't sound like your "random function" would qualify, but you'd have to describe it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Maclaurin series has any special physical significance that is different from the Taylor series. But then for some functions it is desirable to have a series expansion at the origin even though it is singular at the origin. Maclaurin series requires that the function is analytic everywhere within the circle of convergence so it can not be used, that is where the Taylor series which can do the expansion about any point in is used.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to describe the purpose of these series as succinctly as possible it would be these three words: **to handle complexity**.

What do I mean by this? Lets suppose we need to describe some function $\mathbb{R}^M\to\mathbb{R}^N$. The cardinality of the set of all such functions is $2^{\beth_1} = 2^{\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)}$: the cardinality of the powerset of the continuum (and thus, by [Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), a strictly bigger cardinality than that of the continuum).

In contrast, the set of all statements in a finitely generated languages (English, German, Mandarin .... mathematics as done by the inhabitants on this planet at least) is countable: the cardinality of all possible descriptions in such a language is $\aleph_0$.

So, in restricting ourselves to Taylor series defined functions, we are taming the collection of all possible functions to something that our finitely generated languages can describe. Our human descriptive powers fail long before specifying something out of a set of cardinality $2^{\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)}$. It's much easier to think of and describe a countable, discrete list of co-efficients than a general function $\mathbb{R}^M\to\mathbb{R}^N$.

We are also heeding the experimental evidence that many things seem to vary smoothly. Smooth isn't quite the same as analytic (defined by a Taylor series), but analyticity given smoothness doesn't seem to be an unreasonable model of this observed smoothness.

The significance of Maclaurin and Taylor series when defining fields or other functions of co-ordinates to physics is the same: the former being a translated, "canonical" version of the latter (we can redefine our co-ordinates to put an "origin" at any point in question).

Comment: $\aleph_1$ cannot be proved in ZFC to be equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$. As a matter of fact, mathematicians nowadays think it is not true. The cardinality of reals, anyways, is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @yuggib  Well if you choose to forswear the continuum hypothesis, write $\beth_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and reread!

Comment: well, apart from cantor seems that most of the great people working in logic do not believe the CH to be true...obviously since it is not provable is only a matter of taste ;-)

Comment: @yuggib well it would certainly make my day if I woke up and read that someone had found something in between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$ .... I think perhaps only discovering life on other planets would be more exciting.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but no one could (at least by constructive means)...finding alien life is surely more plausible :-D